# Can I open ports on Azure Websites?

Tags: wcf, azure, azure-web-app-service, ports

If I want to self host WCF in a Windows Azure Website by spinning up my own ServiceHost can I host end points on 8080 or any other port I want to? Is there any specific usable range of ports I have access to or is port access entirely blocked?

**Edit:** for absolute clarification this question is **NOT** about web or worker roles and is **only** about Azure **Websites**

Comment: If you don't want to use a web role, you can't do what you want.

Comment: @PeterRitchie or anyone else, someone should make that an answer, preferable with a citation somewhere showing that to be true.

Comment: That's why it's a comment, there's no comprehensive list of things Azure Web Sites *doesn't* do.

Comment: We are working on a solution on top of cloud services for hosting websites in same way as azure websites do it, but here you get the benefits of being on your own VM and you can configure ports and everything else as you like it. The solutions goal is to make things as easy as azure websites and you do not have to know in depth about cloud services to use it. We are less then a month from releasing it, but feel free to drop me an email pks@composite.net if it something you would consider. I am already using it and spinning services up in the background using owin selfhost next to the websites.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This blog post is slightly out dated now as Windows Azure Websites have more features now (like staging and production slots, WebJobs, etc) but the part regarding ports is still true for Azure Websites.

> *When to use Cloud Services [...] Windows Azure Websites is all IIS, the web server provides the entire platform, there is no room for long running processes or threads that can sit and wait for communication on another port outside of IIS*

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2013/11/21/windows-azure-websites-vs-cloud-services.aspx

**Note that** now you can have a long running process using webjobs that does back-end work, but you can't listen on anything other than 80

Answer (score 7):

No, WAMS won't let you open ports. If you need that, you should host in a Web Role (Cloud services). Then you can configure your endpoints through windows azure management portal.

Comment: But this is the answer: you must use Web Roles!

Comment: I didn't ask what hosting methods in azure will allow me to open my own ports, i specifically asked if WAWS will let me open ports. A very significant distinction.