# Exposing a non http endpoint in azure

Tags: azure, docker, opc-ua

I have an OPC UA server in a docker container. The server exposes a TCP endpoint with the binary opc.tcp protocol. What are possible methods I can use to expose non http endpoints in Azure? Thank you.

This suggested a WCF workaround, but the server is not WCF application.
[How can I host a TCP Listener in Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38333679/how-can-i-host-a-tcp-listener-in-azure)

Answer (score 0):

If it is docker based, but not http, then Microsoft suggested two possible solutions.

1. Azure container instance - deploy a single docker instance via the Azure website, or you can deploy a multi docker instance as a container group via the Azure CLI. For multi docker instances you have limits on CPU and memory as it is running on the same "server" so scaling could be an issue. Adding a static ip is possible and described here [Configure a single public IP address for outbound and inbound traffic to a container group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-egress-ip-address)
2. Use the AKS/Kubernetes cluster in Azure.