# TCP Listener in Container in AWS

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, tcp, listener

Ideally, I'd like to run C sharp TCP Lister App(On Cloud) that can receive TCP messages from various IoT Devices.

My previous attempt to run it on a Container Instance on Azure failed as the Azure only supports HTTP/HTTPS on certain ports and not custom port listening.

How is this case with AWS? Does AWS have restrictions on custom port TCP Listeners?

Comment: I do not think eitherAWS or Azure have such restriction. Which service did you use on Azure side?

Comment: I used the container instance on Azure. It only allows HTTP and not TCP with limited port configuration capabilities.

Refer : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38333679/how-can-i-host-a-tcp-listener-in-azure